# Why did exokernels never take off?

Tags: operating-system, kernel

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exokernel

seems like a great idea. Anyone know why it never took off? I'm geniunely curious why it didn't become popular in niche situations (like servers -- there are things do-able in exokernels that are simply impossible in Linux/BSD).

Thanks!

Note: marked at community wiki as this might be considered discussion oriented.

Comment: Dear trigger happy mods: If your going to close stuff, maybe offer a friendly suggestion/tip as to why, and offer help to the poster as to where he could get help with the question/discussion instead of SO.

Comment: How is the above off-topic? Are operating systems not important to programming or software development? Are operating programs not considered software? Exokernels provides a ways to rapidly prototype new operating systems. Though I guess this answers why exokernels never took off, a bunch of arrogant people thinking it's not software because they don't understand it.

Comment: This question seems pretty on-topic, but was it closed because it is a better fit for one of the other stackexchange sites?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Speculation follows:

To provide a working system (i.e. one for users (even geeky users) instead of one for tinkerers) you're going to have to make all those policy decisions that the exokernel provider declined to make. That is, you going to have to provide one or more schedulers, a disk queueing manager, a network stack, and so *ad nauseam*.

And once you've done that, what have you gained?

Comment: You've gained the ability to use several of those abstractions at once, securely. Different applications can make different tradeoffs without stepping on each other's toes and still run on the same system. Think virtual machines with no overhead.